# Video poster disappears after one play on the iPad 2

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, video, mediaelement.js

On iPad 2 we have have a problem with poster image for video disappearing after video has been played. It displays black image instead of the poster image.

There's no problem with displaying poster image when page loads. It just is not displayed again when the video has ended.

Have you ever encounter anything like this and have a known solution?

I'm not sure if that's important but we use MediaElement.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on the iphone 3GS, as a workaround, I stored the poster frames in a Javascript object and then replaced them after the video finished playing. Maybe this would work for you also as you have the poster frames showing on page load.

Answer (score 1):

The poster image isn't supposed to be displayed once the video has finished playing. You'll need to build something that redisplays it yourself, such as Neil mentioned.